# Parsing XML file in java with conflicting tags

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML file to parse in java and use the elements of that XML file in google map..
Below is the xml that i have to parse.

```
      <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
      <rss version="2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
       <channel>
       <title/>
       <link/>
       <description/>
       <item>
        <title> hang </title>
        <description>Total: 291830</description>
         <geo:lat>52.0</geo:lat>
         <geo:long>-6.0</geo:long>
         <dc:subject>category1</dc:subject>
          </item>
          <item>
         <title> system </title>
         <description>Total: 78055</description>
        <geo:lat>36.66992187</geo:lat>
         <geo:long>48.97003173</geo:long>
        <dc:subject>category2</dc:subject>
        </item>
         <item>
          <title>chill </title>
         <description>Total: 43688</description>
         <geo:lat>2.0</geo:lat>
         <geo:long>3.8</geo:long>
         <dc:subject>category3</dc:subject>
          </item>
          </channel>
           </rss>
```

The title and the description which is at the top is getting conflicted with the title and description which is inside the root node item.Can anybody help me to parse the xml and take the values of title and description??

Comment: Why is this a conflict? This looks like valid XML which should be parseable.

Comment: it is getting confused with the title and description tag which is at the top and which is inside the root node  item.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to search/query an XML file, XPath tends to be a good choice, assuming you're using the DOM...

```
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document dom = db.parse(new File("test.xml"));
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    // Find the "thing" node...
    XPathExpression expession = xpath.compile("/rss/channel/item/title | /rss/channel/item/description");
    NodeList nl = (NodeList) expession.evaluate(dom, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    for (int index = 0; index < nl.getLength(); index++) {
        Node node = nl.item(index);
        System.out.println(node.getNodeName() + " = " + node.getTextContent());
    }

} catch (Exception exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output

```
title =  hang 
description = Total: 291830
title =  system 
description = Total: 78055
title = chill 
description = Total: 43688
```

Take a look at the [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) for more details...

Comment: im able to get the values of title and description but im unable to get the values of geo:lat because of the colon...how do i get that value??

Comment: No , i had not tried it before...It works with lat...Thak u so much...:)